# How to connect an android client to a server written in C?

Tags: android, c, sockets

I need to connect an android client to a server written in C. I am actually developing a simple chat application.

Comment: Use NDK and C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use socket, both Android's Java and C have it. You can read the documentation.

Or, here's the fast way. Just create Android Socket client as https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/ does and create server as https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_server_example.htm does.

Here's the snippet:

`client.java`

```
package com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Client extends Activity {

    private Socket socket;

    private static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.2";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      

        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            String str = et.getText().toString();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println(str);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

`server.c` in *NIX environment.

```
/*
    C socket server example
*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>    //write

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , read_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char client_message[2000];

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    //accept connection from an incoming client
    client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Connection accepted");

    //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(client_sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
        //Send the message back to client
        write(client_sock , client_message , strlen(client_message));
    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the server port `5000` in the client match the actual server port `8888`?